# Subversion has disabled write permissions to directory

Tags: bash, svn, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10. Svn directory structure is as follows:
/student/2017/s1/EM/otherdirs

I recently restructured a committed directory (called EM) locally, and when I was trying to commit the changes on svn I made a mistake somewhere (lots of attempts of deleting/adding directory) and now the parent directory of EM (s1) has no write permissions.

```
Running ls -l in 2017 dir:  
dr-xr-xr-x 2 root root 0 May 6 11:01 s1  
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 0 May 7 13:57 s2
```

I have tried running the chmod and chown commands on s1 as suggested by other questions on SE but they are not working.

This all happened yesterday and I can't remember exactly the error svn gave me but it had something to do with the WC db (not sure what that is). How can I make the dir s1 writable?

EDIT: Solved. Bash on Ubuntu on Windows terminal was not working using accepted answer, so I tried using running Cygwin as administrator and was able to change the permissions

Comment: What is the exact `chmod` command you tried?

Comment: Tried a whole variation of chmods. I am running: sudo chmod u+w s1/ What do you suggest?

Comment: See my answer. I briefly explain how `chmod` works so you can decide what to do for your specific case.

Comment: That should theoretically work, but you may need the `recursive` argument  flag.

Comment: When you did `ls -l`, were you signed in as `root`?

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure I am root. whoami returns "Jarrah".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chmod a+w s1` will give all users write access. Since it's a directory, you may need to apply write access to every file in the directory. The following code will do it:

```
chmod -R a+w s1
```

To explain the `chmod` command more in-depth, there are 9 permission categories. There are 3 types of permissions (read, write, execute), and 3 groups (owner, group, other). The owner is quite simply the owner of the file. `group` consists of all users in the same "group" as the owner; that includes all `sudo` users if the owner is `sudo`. Typically this is not used too much. `others` includes everyone else.

The way `chmod` is usually used is like so:

```
chmod [-R] [u][g][o][a][+|-][r][w][x]
```

Use `-R` to apply recursively to all subelements of a directory. The first part looks like this:

```
chmod [-R] [u][g][o][a]
```

`u` specifies that the changes will apply to the owner. `g` includes the group. `o` includes all others. `a` includes everyone (thus making it equivalent to `ugo`).

The second part looks like this:

```
chmod [-R] <target>[+|-][r][w][x]
```

`+` adds the permissions to the target, and `-` removes them. `r` for read, `w` for write, and `x` for execute.

This means that for your case, depending on whether you only want yourself to have write-access or if you want everyone to get write access, use something along the lines of:

```
chmod [-R] a+w s1
```

or replacing `a` with the appropriate target.

Comment: Remember to use `sudo`, not `root`, if you want to change the owner/group.

Comment: I've used chmod before but thanks for going into detail. Cleared some things up. sudo chmod -R a+w s1 with and without the -R is not working, still no changes

Comment: @Jarrah Is it throwing any errors? Is there any output?

Comment: no errors, no nothing. doing a ls -l directly afterwards shows no changes. I tried it on a test file and it didn't change anything...so then I tried it with cygwin and it worked for the test file but I get permission denied with dir s1. When I try sudo in cygwin, it says "sudo not found".

Comment: @Jarrah Try creating a new file `test.txt`, running `chmod a-rwx test.txt`, and then try opening it. Tell me what happens.

Comment: I tried something similar before, but doing that, `test.txt` lost only its write permissions: `-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 0 ...`
Just tried same thing in cygwin and the result is `-rwx------+`

Comment: @Jarrah So after removing read+write+execute permissions, only the write permissions were changed? That's strange.

Comment: I have a feeling this has to do with the Bash on Ubuntu on Windows terminal being buggy. Cygwin is giving me different results.

Comment: @Jarrah Right, I was going off of pure Unix BASH. Anyway, glad it works out now!

Answer (score 0):

Chmod and chown should work.
Try sudo'g coz the owner may be root and your id may not have the root user permissions.
Chmod and chown should work, no reason why they can't work.

Comment: there are a number of reasons why these commands might not work: e.g. not all filesystems  support permissions.

Comment: In this specific case I don't see any reason .

Comment: I have tried before and just tried again, still not working :/ I am running: sudo chmod u+w s1/ and have tried with chown and others.

Comment: Do you have chmod and chown installed on the box.

Comment: @RiteshKumar I do have sudo permissions. Please see response in comments to Hypers answer